# What is the total derivative of $f(x,y) = 2x+xy^2$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

There are some questions on this site about confusion with the total derivative, and to see if I got it after reading them, I tried to see the difference between the partial derivative w.r.t. x and the total derivative w.r.t. x of $f(x,y) = 2x+xy^2.$

This part itself is easy enough:

1. Partial derivative -
   $\frac{\partial{}f}{\partial{}x} = 2+y^2$
2. Total derivative -
   $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial{}f}{\partial{}x}+\frac{\partial{}f}{\partial{}y}\frac{dy}{dx}$
   $\implies$ $\frac{df}{dx}=2+y^2+2xy\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$

At this point, I wanted to see what would happen if there was a known relationship. I choose polar coordinates, $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. This leads to the relation $\frac{y}{x}=\tan\theta \implies y=x\tan\theta$

This is where I'm not sure what to do. What I did at first was use this to say $\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan\theta \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}\implies\frac{df}{dx}=2+y^2+2xy\cdot\frac{y}{x}=2+3y^2$

Is this the correct solution? Or should I have said that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan\theta+\frac{\partial{}y}{\partial\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dx}$

Then you would end up with a more complicated answer that depends on the derivative of $\theta$ w.r.t. x. This anwser seems weird to me, since it starts from a relatively simple formula, but it also makes sense that it would still depend on $\theta$ in some way, because x and y depend on $\theta$ (if you eliminate r)

Which is correct? Or are both wrong and should I have done something else?

Comment: You're running into the problem that you used a change of coordinates that treats $x$ and $y$ as co-equal, independent coordinates and transformed them together into two other independent coordinates. Now you have found that leads to an ambiguity when you try to define $y=y(x)$ because you have too many degrees of freedom. What you are doing is no longer defined so either interpretation could get you what you want ("total" derivative in your original vs transformed coordinates, which will not be the same thing).

Comment: As a side note, I've also heard the phrase total derivative refer to the gradient instead $$\frac{d f}{d\mathbf{r}} = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$ since it describes the "total" change of the function and gives you the total differential of the function in any direction you want: $$df = \frac{df}{d\mathbf{r}}\cdot \Delta \mathbf{r}$$ Your total derivative is simply the special case where the direction we take the derivative in is defined by $$\Delta \mathbf{r} = \left(1,\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, if there was some relation y=y(x) that did not depend on any other variable ($\theta$), then it would have worked. But because I chose the relation poorly, it did not make sense to speak of the total derivative w.r.t. x anymore?

Comment: Yes that is correct.